# Stencil drag and drop sortable list without libraries

Tags: css, drag-and-drop, jsx, draggable, stenciljs

I need to replicate [this exact same sortable list](https://codepen.io/scottdavis/pen/DBXLjb), but using Stencil with no outside libraries. Does anyone has an example? Best I've done so far is a normal drag and drop sortable list, but items don't move upwards or interchange places as I'm dragging them. I've been looking everywhere and I couldn't find a single example that looks like this or has this characteristics (and those who are close, use libraries). I hope you can help me... thank you in advance!

This is some code from the link that shows it uses a library:

```
ul.addEventListener('slip:beforereorder', function(e){
  if (/demo-no-reorder/.test(e.target.className)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);
```

I can't add my code because is work related and has confidentiality clauses.

Comment: If you don't want dependencies (strange limitation, Stencil itself is an unrequired dependency), you have to look at the source code of D&D libraries like: https://anseki.github.io/plain-draggable/

Comment: @PeterJames I can't add my code because is work related and has confidentiality clauses. But my question is if you have seen an example without libraries like this, because I've been googling like crazy and nothing.

Comment: @Danny '365CSI' Engelman great idea! Thank you!

Comment: @PeterJames I edited but it wouldn't let me post without code so I just used some from the codepen. In any case, my question stands.

Answer (score 0):

Danny '365CSI' Engelman answered "If you don't want dependencies (strange limitation, Stencil itself is an unrequired dependency), you have to look at the source code of D&D libraries like: anseki.github.io/plain-draggable" and it was the best idea ever. Thank you so much!!